# How can I conjugate English words to the progressive form in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

I have looked at `pattern.en`'s `conjugate`, but it only conjugates into a few forms, and I would rather not have to sit down and program all of the exceptions to those rules that would allow me to make conjugations such as

- free - freeing
- eat - eating
- bathe - bathing
- be - being
- ban - banning

`nltk` has stemming, but it doesn't seem to have the reverse operation, at least from searching StackOverflow. This seems like a very elementary NLP task, but I cannot find anything modern that does this in Python. Any general conjugation tool would be nice, although the progressive form in English doesn't have irregularities I know of.

I am also trying to see if there are exceptions to this rule, which might work as an alternate function:

```
def present_to_progressive(x):
    vowels = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
    size = len(x)
    if size == 2:
        return x + 'ing'
    elif x[size - 2:] == 'ie':
        return x[:(size-2)] + 'ying'
    elif x[size - 1] not in vowels and x[size - 2] not in vowels:
        return x + 'ing'
    elif x[size - 1] == 'e' and x[size-2] not in vowels:
        return x[0:(size-1)] + 'ing'
    elif x[size - 1] not in vowels and x[size-2] in vowels:
        if x[size - 3] not in vowels:
             return x + x[size-1] + 'ing'
        else:
             return x + 'ing'
    else:
        return x + 'ing'
```

*Edit: Added case for "ie" verbs*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an entire library for this type of modification that does what you want. It is called pattern.en

you can find it here:
[pattern.en](https://github.com/clips/pattern)

It is a good source.

Here is an excerpt from the conjugation tutorial on the site:

```
conjugate(verb, 
    tense = PRESENT,        # INFINITIVE, PRESENT, PAST, FUTURE
   person = 3,              # 1, 2, 3 or None
   number = SINGULAR,       # SG, PL
     mood = INDICATIVE,     # INDICATIVE, IMPERATIVE, CONDITIONAL, SUBJUNCTIVE
   aspect = IMPERFECTIVE,   # IMPERFECTIVE, PERFECTIVE, PROGRESSIVE 
  negated = False,          # True or False
    parse = True)
```

It is quite useful and very expansive!

Comment: Okay, I think I overlooked the aspect parameter initially. This should do the trick for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code covers most cases. I checked with a list of 620 irregular verbs taken from [this site](https://www.usingenglish.com/download/irregular-verbs-viewer.html) and it misses approximately 84 cases.

```
with open('/tmp/Verblist.vrb', 'rt') as f:
    err = 0
    for l in f:
        if l.startswith('>'):
            forms = l[1:].split(' ')
            guess = present_to_progressive(forms[0])
            if forms[4].lower() != guess.lower():
                print('CHECK: {} {} {}'.format(forms[0], forms[4], guess))
                err += 1
    print(err)
```

Just by adding `'w','y'` to your list of vowels, the list of possible mistakes goes down to 18 cases:

```
CHECK: Aby/Abey Abying/Abeying Aby/Abeying    -- Correct
CHECK: Eat Eating Eatting
CHECK: Fordo/Foredo Fordoing Fordo/Foredoing  -- Correct in one of the 2 variants
CHECK: Forget Foregetting Forgetting          -- Correct, the list has a typo
CHECK: Lie Lying Lieing                       -- Fixed in your second version
CHECK: Mischoose Mischoosins Mischoosing      -- Correct, the list has a typo
CHECK: Miswed Miswedding Misweding
CHECK: Outswim Outswimming Outswiming
CHECK: Overlie Overlying Overlieing           -- Fixed in your second version
CHECK: Quit Quitting Quiting
CHECK: Relearn Relearn Relearning
CHECK: Rewed Rewedding Reweding
CHECK: Rewet Rewetting Reweting
CHECK: Rewin Rewinning Rewining
CHECK: Swim Swimming Swiming
CHECK: Underlie Underlying Underlieing        -- Fixed in your second version
CHECK: Vex Vexing Vexxing
CHECK: Zinc Zincking Zincing
```

The most important of these could be addressed adding the special case "lie" and improving the rule on doubling the last consonant. I guess you may decide to safely ignore some very uncommon verbs.